# How to get html5 video work on android 4.3

Tags: javascript, cordova, html5-video

I have an app where some videos are placed using html5 video tag. It works fine in Chrome Browser (desktop), but does not play on android (tested on tablet with android 4.3). It just shows player with black background (no video).

I have tested with my Nexus 5 (android 5.1.1) and it works fine.

Î have tried this html:

```
                <video id="video" controls>
                    <source src="../videos/portfolio.mp4">
                    <img src="../images/pf_preview.png" width="100%"/>
                        Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
                </video>

               <script>var video = document.getElementById('video');
                    video.addEventListener('click',function(){
                    video.play();
                },false); </script>
```

I deleted type of video, and put the js code to play video manually. But it still fails to play.

Any ideas how to fix it?

Best

Comment: Have you tried other video formats? Perhaps `ogv` or `webm` would do the trick.

Comment: Converted to webm, but still the same behavior.